# Count date and show into comma separated values in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
cola int,
colb date
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into test values(111,'2014-3-2');
insert into test values(111,'2014-3-3');
insert into test values(111,'2014-3-2');
insert into test values(121,'2014-4-1');
insert into test values(121,'2014-4-2');
insert into test values(121,'2014-4-3');
insert into test values(121,'2014-4-4');
insert into test values(131,'2014-5-1');
insert into test values(131,'2014-5-1');
```

**Note**: I want to show `cola` who is entered in the specific date. And want to count that distinct dates which is present in 
the `colb` column occured for specific `cola`. And want to show comma separted dates along to specific `cola` values.

**Expected Result**:

```
cola    CountOfDates                  colb
-----------------------------------------------------------------
111         2          2014-03-02,2014-03-03
121         4          2014-04-01,2014-04-02,2014-04-03,2014-04-04 
131         1          2014-05-01
```

**Explanation of result**: The above result shows that `cola` entered in 3 dates but the distinct are 2.Like that the other values are appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Xml Path()` trick with `Distinct Count` of `colb` to do this.

```
SELECT cola,
       Count(distinct colb)                             Countofdates,
       Stuff((SELECT Distinct ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), colb )
              FROM   #test t
              WHERE  t.cola = a.cola
              FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') colb
FROM   #test a
GROUP  BY cola
```

**Result**

```
cola    Countofdates    colb
----    ------------    -------------------------------------------
111     2               2014-03-02,2014-03-03
121     4               2014-04-01,2014-04-02,2014-04-03,2014-04-04
131     1               2014-05-01
```

Comment: looks like you need to distinct `Countofdates`  :)

Comment: @Andrey - Already am Counting only distinct `colb`. Try executing the query :)

Comment: well then you forgot to change Result in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this (version without using XML - clear set-base approach with recursive CTE)

```
with [base] as
(
    select cola, cast(colb as nvarchar(max)) [colb], 1 [count] from test
    union all
    select b.cola, b.colb+ ',' + cast(t.colb as nvarchar(10)), [count]+1
    from [base] b
    join test t on t.cola = b.cola
        and b.colb not like '%' + cast(t.colb as nvarchar(10)) + '%'
)
, ranked as
(
    select cola
    , colb
    , [count]
    , row_number() over (partition by cola order by [count] desc) [rank] 
    from [base]
)
select cola, colb, [count] from ranked where [rank] = 1
```

Result

```
cola    colb                                            count
-------------------------------------------------------------
111     2014-03-02,2014-03-03                           2
121     2014-04-01,2014-04-02,2014-04-03,2014-04-04     4
131     2014-05-01                                      1
```

Comment: looks like he need `Distinct colb` rows and `Distinct count`